# When the fourier series equal to the original function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in L^2([-1/2,1/2])$.

Define $a_n=\int_{[-1/2,1/2]} f(x) e^{-2\pi i n x} dx$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Define $S_N(x)=\sum_{n=-N}^N a_n e^{2\pi i n x}$ for each $N\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that $S_N\rightarrow f$ in $L^2$-norm, but I'm curious whether $S_N\rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e.. What more conditions should one assume to assert that $S_N\rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e.? How do I prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general statement is a very difficult problem solved in the 20th century, the result is called Carleson's theorem. It says in particular that the Fourier series of a $L^2$ periodic function converges to it a.e.

Weaker theorems, e.g. by assuming the function is continuous and bounded variation, are much easier to prove.

Comment: is it specific to the Fourier series ? I guess there is something more general in term of orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,1])$ of smooth functions ? all we have to prove is that if $f \in L^2([0,1])$ has support $[a,b]$, then $f_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \langle e_n, f \rangle e_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ on $[0,1] \setminus [a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 No, it is not straightforward to generalize to another orthonormal basis of $L^2$.

Comment: yes you are right, I believe I was thinking to the pointwise convergence on an interval onto which $f$ is continuous